# How to make track automation in Logic Pro X be independent from the mixer so automation is applied relative to the mixer faders?

Tags: automation, logic

I'd like to have Logic Pro's automation feature work as in other DAWs where even if you have track automation or "envelopes" applied to a track, you can still use the track faders in the mixer to affect the general volume of the track, instead of having the automation actually move the faders. Is that possible?

Comment: Is it 'trim' automation mode that you're looking for ?

Comment: I've already tried all modes (Read, Touch, Trim, Write, etc.) but none of them achieve that, because using, for example, Trim, as you suggested, actually changes the automation levels in the part where the playing cursor is. I just want the mixer faders to affect the whole track proportionately to their automation, so moving up the fader for a track, say, 2dB, would apply +2dB to the whole track, no matter the automation status in each moment of the track.

Comment: I have the same question here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/125335/is-relative-automation-broken-in-10-6-2. I appreciate that there are workarounds like automating Gain instead of main volume but it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to have the output of the track go to a bus, instead of output 1-2.  Then you could either used the fader on the bus, instead of the track, or you could put the automation on the bus track (your would need to create a track for the bus to be able to automate on it).

You could also use a plugin and automate the output volume of the plugin instead of automating the track volume.  You would want to make sure the plugin is the last in the signal chain for that track to avoid the automation affecting other aspects of the signal chain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using a bus could do the trick, but it's a bit cumbersome having to create a bus for each track. I guess I'll have to adapt to Logic's way of working.

Comment: I think it would be less cumbersome to use a plugin and automate the output gain there, personally.

Comment: Could you please explain how would I go the plugin route? Wouldn't I still have to automate each track plugin separately? Also, what plugin would be better for this? Sorry for the "noob" questions.

Comment: @OMA The idea is that you are automating the output gain of a plugin instead of the gain of the track itself, allowing you to use the slider.  So yes, you would have to automate each track/plugin separately in the same way you would have to automate the volume of each track separately.  I'd recommend using the Gain plugin, found under Utility, as that shouldn't affect anything else about the track (a lot of plugins can change the tonal quality of the track).

Comment: If you're not familiar with automating anything other than track volume, you can access this from the automation view.  When it says "Main: Volume", click to open the dropdown.  You should see each plugin shown there and you would just go into the Gain plugin and select Gain to choose that parameter to automate.  You can do this with all sorts of things, like automating filters on a virtual instrument, or automating the panning of the track.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: Well I've actually tried your Gain plugin suggestion (inside Utility category) and it's just what I was looking for. I've added the Gain plugin  to all tracks and then I can automate the gain in each track while still being able to use the mixer faders. Pretty straightforward. The only downside is that if I use some of Logic's instrument presets, it overwrites the Gain plugin and the automation I had done until then in that track, but it's a small issue. Usually, presets, if used at all, are applied at the beginning of working with a track and then tweaked from there, so no biggie. Thx again!

Comment: @OMA glad that it’s helpful for you. It is possible to copy automation data, so you might be able to try that. I’d create a new track for the preset inst, add the gain plugin, then drag the audio or midi regions to the new track. It should ask if you want to copy automation data at that point. I’m not sure what will happen if you drag the regions before adding the plugin to the new track though.